# Jquery Check if image done loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following to refresh the images which i'm using to prevents bots. So i want to show some GIF while the image is loading and hide it when loading is done.

```
$.CaptchaLoad = function(){
    var src   = '../php/captcha.php',
        stamp = (new Date()).getTime(),
        url   = src + '?' + stamp;
    document.getElementById('capcha').src = url;

};
```

Is in Ajax where i would use 'Success';

Comment: try `onload` event of image: `document.getElementById('capcha').onload = function(){};`

Comment: with jQuery, can do something like `$("#capcha").load(function(){});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what $.CaptchaLoad plugin? 
if above code works fine in your case.

Add onload listener to image object.

```
$("#capcha").on("load",function(){
    //successfully loaded
    //write a code here to hide your loader.
});
```

Comment: $.on is preferred to $.bind in new versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event.

```
$("#capcha").load(function(){
    //hide your GIF
});
```

But notice that there are some Caveats of the load event when used with images, quoted from the doc:

- It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
- It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as
  before
- It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
- Can cease to
  fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

One of them is : Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache. In your case, adding the timestamp does the trick. Remember not to remove it.